# Unable to cast string to TimeSpan

Tags: c#-4.0, timespan

I've a string which is in `"hh\:mm\:ss\.ff"` format (example, 00:00:00.10). When I am trying to parse this `string` to `TimeSpan`, it is losing its customized format and returns me `"00:00:00.1000000"` which is `TimeSpan.FromSeconds` format.
I do not want to display this long result on my UI, and that is the reason I am customizing the format. I've also tried `TimeSpan.ParseExact` but same result. Any suggestions?

Code:

```
TimeSpan ts = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(remainingTime);
string hhmmss = ts.ToString(@"hh\:mm\:ss\.ff");
ts = TimeSpan.Parse(hhmmss);
//ts = TimeSpan.ParseExact(hhmmss, @"hh\:mm\:ss\.ff", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, TimeSpanStyles.None);
```

Result: `00:00:00.1000000`

Expected Result: `00:00:00.10`

Screen Shot :
[image]

Comment: Why aren't you just displaying the string?  Of course the `TimeSpan` value is going to have whatever precision it has -- that's why you format it when converting to a string.

Comment: Well this change is in existing functionality which is using `TimeSpan` in most of the places. I do not want to make multiple changes in existing code. That would be my last option.

Comment: Can you give an example of code that is displaying the `TimeSpan` value?  There may be an easier solution, but in general, formatting happens when converting to a string.  Also, the answer may depend on the UI technology -- is this a WPF app?  Web app?  Windows forms?

Comment: That's just the way the debugger displays a TimeSpan, it shows all the significant digits.  You don't have a problem.  If you *really* want to have it in a specific format then you must use its ToString() method.